# Codename One - rim.obfuscation build hint

Tags: codenameone, obfuscation

About obfuscation, what is the meaning of "[rim.obfuscation](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html)"? I didn't find on Internet what is the "rimc compiler".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a legacy build hint related to RIM (Blackberry) support. Since that support is deprecated we removed some of the docs for it.

Our old plugin UI in the preferences still has UI for this and adds those hints automatically. We hope to remove that UI on NetBeans/Eclipse so only Codename One Settings remains but removing code is sometimes just as hard as adding it.